# Getting value of a nested object in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the **req1** value in the JSON below, programatically.Here **RequestTypeItem** can be changed as well, so it is not fixed. Else I could have navigated it using **object.subobject**

I was able to navigate till **slots** using

```
var b = JSON.parse("{ .... }");
b.request.intent.slots.RequestTypeItem.value
```

But I can navigate further programatically.

```
{"request": {
  "locale": "en-US",
  "timestamp": "2016-09-25T00:36:14Z",
  "type": {
    "name": "request",
    "slots": {
      "RequestTypeItem": {
        "name": "RequestTypeItem",
        "value": "req1"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON your request does not have a property of *intent*, it does have a property *type*, so you then you can access the property you want with

```
b.request.type.slots.RequestTypeItem.value
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cexbn54/

Edit: After reading your question again, maybe this is what you want:

```
 // loop through all properties on the slots object
for (var i in b.request.type.slots) {
    if (b.request.type.slots.hasOwnProperty(i)) {  // make sure it is a property belonging directly to slots, and not "inherited" from the prototype chain
    if (b.request.type.slots[i].value) { // make sure that the sub-property of slots has a value property
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = b.request.type.slots[i].value;
      break; // break out of the loop after getting a value
    }  
  }
}
```

Here I loop through all the properties on slots, checking that the property does indeed belong to slots, and that it has value property.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cexbn54/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had given a link which some of you found it not useful.
Here is what would get to req1:

[image]

```
 $data=@'
[{"request": {
  "locale": "en-US",
  "timestamp": "2016-09-25T00:36:14Z",
  "type": {
    "name": "request",
    "slots": {
      "RequestTypeItem": {
        "name": "RequestTypeItem",
        "value": "req1"
      }
    }
  }
}
}]
'@
$json=ConvertFrom-Json $data
$json.request.type.slots.RequestTypeItem.value
```